# Can't install any applications on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: apt, dependencies, raspberrypi

I am running Ubuntu LTS 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

Every time I try to install software I get a broken package error saying something like this:

```
Depends: libc6:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm trying to install the software by using:

```
sudo apt install ./app.deb
```

I have also tried gdebi, dpkg and aptitude to install my software.

Of course this error changes for the different dependencies, that is an example of one. All the dependencies are installed on their latest version. I have tested this many times by trying to install Discord, Minecraft, MongoDB Software, Balena Etcher and a few others. They have all returned that error. Is there any way to fix this?

**Note:** If I am missing some details or the community asks for something to be added, I will add it.

I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) and it still gives something along the lines of unmet dependencies.

Comment: Not all software can be run on this platform. Please give more details on what you were trying to install and how?

Comment: I'm really at this point just trying to install any software not provided by apt. Nothing seems to be working so even if I manage to install some random app, I'll be a bit relieved. As for how I will edit my question.

Comment: Please give an example on what software are you trying to install. What exactly file you download, etc.

Comment: You can't install `amd64` debs anyway.

Comment: I've given examples. One is Minecraft which I mainly want to install. Is there a reason why I can't install `amd64` software? I have added `amd64` to Multiarch.

Comment: Please give an example of `app.deb`.

Comment: For Minecraft it's Minecraft.deb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 4 has an `arm` CPU. It can't run `amd64` or `i386` binary code.

So you can't install or run `amd64` or `i386` software.

You need to search for `arm64` packages, or build software from source.